# Default search not working with select when using in a loop

Tags: antd

Default search not working if I use select with mode multiple in a loop. other all working fine. anything wrong with my code?

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                                <Select
                                    mode="multiple"
                                    size={'large'}
                                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                    placeholder={<Icon type="search" style={{ fontSize: 13 }} />}
                                    onChange={this.handleChange}
                                    >
                                    {this.createOptions(items[i].default_values)}
                                </Select>}
```

Briefly expline - I am trying to create a filter block with different fields like select, input etc with from a JSON data. In this scenario, I need to iterate both select box and options based on the data. One thing I noticed that the last select box from the iteration working as expected, so I think I need to bind the options along with an appropriate select box or some approaches like this, but I don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to loop are the `<options />` tags, not the `<Select />`

```
    <Select
         mode="multiple"
         size={'large'}
         style={{ width: '100%' }}
         placeholder={<Icon type="search" style={{ fontSize: 13 }} />}
         onChange={this.handleChange}
     >
       for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
                                    return this.createOptions(items[i].default_values)
          }
    </Select>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your reply, I am trying to create a filter block with different fields like select, input etc with from a JSON data. In this scenario, I need to iterate both select box and options based on the data. One thing I noticed that the last select box from the iteration working as expected, so I think I need to bind the options along with an appropriate select box or some approaches like this, but I don't know how to do this. for your information, I have used this function for loop and create options - {this.createOptions(items[i].default_values)}

Comment: got it, if that is true, I don't think you need to bind the options to the select, I think the problem is probably beyond antd. puting more codes may help

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am trying to make a fiddle and update here.